# MobileSafari not returning the right image size info via JavaScript

Tags: javascript, image, mobile-safari

I have an HTML [test page for this issue here](http://still-island-1941.herokuapp.com/sizetest.html). For some reason **MobileSafari is reporting the `Image.width/height` properties of any image with more than 1700 pixels as half its value**. That is, the `width` property of the JPG is, say, 2000 but MobileSafari JavaScript reports it as 1000. If I try the same code with a 1700px-wide image I get the correct width.

[The test](http://still-island-1941.herokuapp.com/sizetest.html) I did loads two images (same image in different dimensions) and displays the JavaScript size values. I tried in:

- Chrome 22, Safari 5.1.7, Firefox 15.0.1 all in Mac OS X 10.6.8 (correct size)
- iOS Simulator 4.3 SDK 3.2 (incorrect size)
- iPad 2 with iOS 5.1 (incorrect size)
- iPhone 4S with iOS 5.1 (incorrect size)

Any ideas why this is happening? Am I missing a setting somewhere? Why does it work with some images but not others?

The test is here: http://still-island-1941.herokuapp.com/sizetest.html

This is the JavaScript code:

```js
    var imgBig, imgSmall;

    function init() {
        imgBig = new Image();
        imgBig.onload = handleBig;
        imgBig.src = "/images/size.jpg";
        imgSmall = new Image();
        imgSmall.onload = handleSmall;
        imgSmall.src = "/images/test1.jpg";
        document.getElementById("browser").innerHTML = navigator.userAgent;
    }

    function handleBig() {
        document.getElementById("dimensionsBig").innerHTML = imgBig.width + "x" + imgBig.height;
        document.getElementById("testBig").src = imgBig.src;
    }

    function handleSmall() {
        document.getElementById("dimensionsSmall").innerHTML = imgSmall.width + "x" + imgSmall.height;
        document.getElementById("testSmall").src = imgSmall.src;
    }
```

This is the HTML code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1"/> 
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>

    <title>MobileSafari image dimensions test</title>
</head>
<body onload="init()">
    <p>your browser: <strong><span id="browser"></span></strong></p>
    <p>big image dimensions: <strong><span id="dimensionsSmall"></span></strong> (should be 1700x1134)</p>
    <img id="testSmall" />
    <p>small image dimensions: <strong><span id="dimensionsBig"></span></strong> (should be 2000x1334)</p>
    <img id="testBig" />
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: In my case I was loading an image 3000px square, and Javascript in iOS was telling me the onload event had fired OK, yet the reported height and width at that moment were zero. I assume I have the same issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it exists a limitation in size and weight.

Because of the memory available on iOS, there are limits on the number of resources it can process:

The maximum size for **decoded** GIF, PNG, and TIFF images is 3 megapixels for devices with less than 256 MB RAM and 5 megapixels for devices with greater or equal than 256 MB RAM.
That is, ensure that **width * height ≤ 3 * 1024 * 1024** for devices with less than 256 MB RAM. 
Note that **the decoded size is far larger than the encoded size** of an image :

> The maximum **decoded** image size for JPEG is 32 megapixels using
>   subsampling. JPEG images can be up to 32 megapixels due to
>   subsampling, which allows JPEG images to decode to a size that has one
>   sixteenth the number of pixels. JPEG images larger than 2 megapixels
>   are subsampled—that is, decoded to a reduced size. JPEG subsampling
>   allows the user to view images from the latest digital cameras.
>
> The maximum size for a canvas element is 3 megapixels for devices with
>   less than 256 MB RAM and 5 megapixels for devices with greater or
>   equal than 256 MB RAM. The height and width of a canvas object is 150
>   x 300 pixels if not specified.

Some links which could help :

- [Apple official site](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/CreatingContentforSafarioniPhone/CreatingContentforSafarioniPhone.html) : check the Know iOS Resource Limits section
- [Analysis and solution in the comments](http://www.defusion.org.uk/archives/2010/02/19/shrinking-large-background-image-bug-in-iphone-safari/)
- [Workaround](http://roblaplaca.com/blog/2010/05/05/ipad-safari-image-limit-workaround/)

Cheers

Comment: I'm not sure if this is the reason for my problem above since, as you can see in the [test](http://still-island-1941.herokuapp.com/sizetest.html) I made, the "large" image is 2000x1334=2,668,000 which is less than 3x1024x1024=3,145,728 pixels.

Comment: Try to lower the quality (weight) of the picture to see if it changes something.
Have you tried the workaround I gaved to see if it changes anything ?

Comment: I uploaded a new "large" file so compressed (20% quality) it looks terrible... 72kb (compressed)... still no change in dimensions reported by MobileSafari

Comment: The max size apply to **decoded** image - [another link](http://www.defusion.org.uk/archives/2010/02/19/shrinking-large-background-image-bug-in-iphone-safari/) with a solution in the comments

Comment: Yes... I know... I was answering to your "Try to lower the quality (weight) of the picture to see if it changes something."