# Cannot draw on canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I have been trying to insert a canvas on top of some pages, but for some pages it doesn't work. It seems to be me that there is something clearing all canvases on the page, but I couldn't find any calls to .clearRect anywhere in the code on the page.

```
canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
canvas.width = document.width;
canvas.height = document.height;

canvas.style['z-index'] = 999;
canvas.style.position = 'absolute';
canvas.style.top = 0;
canvas.style.left = 0;

document.body.appendChild(canvas);

var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 1000, 1000);
```

A page with the problem is: http://www.nrk.no/sognogfjordane/helse-forde-har-ikkje-full-oversikt-1.11166801

If you run the same code on this page it should work. Expected result is a huge black square on the page.

I don't understand how a script can block the use of an inserted canvas on the page.

I am using Chrome.

*** EDIT ***

The problem is not that I use the deprecated `document.width/height`calls, but that I wasn't aware that canvas has a maximum size: [Maximum size of a <canvas> element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6081483/maximum-size-of-a-canvas-element)

Comment: How and where are you inserting this piece of code? I dumped it into the console and it's working fine for me (Chrome)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I first thought Simon Sarris was correct, but in the end that didn't do what I wanted. What I want is a  that covers the entire page.

I discovered through [Maximum size of a <canvas> element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6081483/maximum-size-of-a-canvas-element) that I was exceeding the limits of canvas.

Answer (score 4):

Because `document.width` and `document.height` are undefined, so your canvas width and height are 0 and 0.

Instead try something like:

```
canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight;

canvas.style['z-index'] = 999;
canvas.style.position = 'absolute';
canvas.style.top = 0;
canvas.style.left = 0;

document.body.appendChild(canvas);

var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 1000, 1000);
```

And you'll see it just fine.

See notes on the [MDN.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.width) Specifically:

> Starting in Gecko 6.0, document.width is no longer supported. Instead, use `document.body.clientWidth`.

Comment: Thank you. This works, but I don't understand why my code will work on some pages, but not on others.

Comment: On second thought, this does not do the same as I want. I want a canvas that covers the entire body of the page, but that exceeds the maximum canvas size on some pages. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6081483/maximum-size-of-a-canvas-element

Answer (score 0):

Please look into the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/deepakb/rwHUX/).

```
canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
canvas.width = document.width;
canvas.height = document.height;

canvas.style['z-index'] = 999;
canvas.style.position = 'absolute';
canvas.style.top = 0;
canvas.style.left = 0;

document.body.appendChild(canvas);

var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 1000, 1000);
```

I think this is what you needed. If you need something else then please exaplin or put your code in jsfiddle. Here in this demo it is creating canvas element.

Comment: If you want specific width and height then you have to specified `document.width` and `document.height` else it will packed the window.