# How to resize an image in Node.js?

Tags: node.js, image-resizing

I am scrapping information from e-commerce websites, in that information image also is there. Downloaded images are in different sizes. I want that images in default size. How to do it Node.js?

Comment: I think you can refer to this question: [resize-a-base-64-image-in-javascript-without-using-canvas](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20958078/resize-a-base-64-image-in-javascript-without-using-canvas)

Comment: Maybe have a look at this node module: http://aheckmann.github.io/gm. It wraps the GraphicsMagick lib into a node module and should provide a lot of functionality to manipulate images.

Answer (score 1):

You can create  a **gulp/grunt** task for this OR you can use available module called **gm** :[GM MODULE](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gm)

```
var gm = require('gm');

gm('/path/to/image.jpg')
.resize(353, 257)
.autoOrient()
.write(writeStream, function (err) {
  if (!err) console.log(' hooray! ');
});
```

Comment: And don't forget to use promises.

Comment: @ManishSingh why?

Answer (score 0):

i have this repo for that purpose just replace your logo.png in the [repo](https://github.com/elhaddajiOtmane/Image-Resizer)

https://github.com/elhaddajiOtmane/Image-Resizer
[image]

```
const sharp = require('sharp');
const sizes = [16, 32, 64, 128,192, 256,512];

sizes.forEach((size) => {
  sharp('logo.png')
    .resize(size, size)
    .toFile(`logo-${size}.png`)
    .then(() => console.log(`Resized to ${size}.png`))
    .catch(err => console.error(err));
});
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35520701)

Answer (score 0):

You can install Image magic software in your system via docker and execute the following command via exec child process. This command should be written inside the bash script.

```
  convert ${IMG1} -resize 141x141^ -gravity center -background "#ffffff" -extent 141x141 ${RAN}_resize_IM1.png
```