# Resizing a image with Javascript without rendering a canvas on the DOM

Tags: javascript, typescript, image-resizing

I've seen this interesting thread among many others: [Resize a Base-64 image in JavaScript without using canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20958078/resize-a-base-64-image-in-javascript-without-using-canvas)

However when i create an off screen canvas using

```
const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
```

the result image is transparent and the size does not even match the parameters.
If i draw on a canvas from the DOM everything works fine

```
const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
```

Here is my resize function that keeps the input image ratio :

```
resizeImage(file) {
    const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    // const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
    const context = (<HTMLCanvasElement>canvas).getContext('2d');
    // set maximum width and height of output image
    const maxW = 400;
    const maxH = 400;
    const img = new Image;

    img.onload = function () {
        const iw = img.width;
        const ih = img.height;
        const scale = Math.min((maxW / iw), (maxH / ih));
        const iwScaled = iw * scale;
        const ihScaled = ih * scale;
        console.log(iwScaled + ' ' + ihScaled);
        (<HTMLCanvasElement>canvas).width = iwScaled;
        (<HTMLCanvasElement>canvas).height = ihScaled;
        context.drawImage(img, 0, 0, iwScaled, ihScaled);
    }
    img.src = URL.createObjectURL(file);
    // retrieve output img in base64 format
    console.log((<HTMLCanvasElement>canvas).toDataURL());
}
```

It takes a file (File) from a HTML input as parameter.
Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you get a Base-64 image when load is complete.

```js
function resizeImage(file) {
      var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
      var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
      var maxW = 400;
      var maxH = 400;
      var img = document.createElement('img');

      img.onload = function() {
        var iw = img.width;
        var ih = img.height;
        var scale = Math.min((maxW / iw), (maxH / ih));
        var iwScaled = iw * scale;
        var ihScaled = ih * scale;
        canvas.width = iwScaled;
        canvas.height = ihScaled;
        context.drawImage(img, 0, 0, iwScaled, ihScaled);
        console.log(canvas.toDataURL());
        document.body.innerHTML+=canvas.toDataURL();
      }
      img.src = URL.createObjectURL(file);
    }
    document.getElementById("file").addEventListener("change", function() {
      file = file.files[0];
      if (file) {
        resizeImage(file);
      }
    });
```

```html
<input id="file" type="file">
```