# Why does iOS fail to render html5 canvas drawing after resize?

Tags: javascript, ios, html, canvas

I have a HTML5 Canvas object, which I resize using Javascript.  I then draw on it.

On iOS, the drawing doesn't show unless I delay the drawing with setTimeout.

So this code shows nothing...

```
myCanvas.width = width;
myContext.strokeStyle = '#000';
myContext.moveTo(0, 0);
myContext.lineTo(2000, 2000);
myContext.stroke();
```

...but this does:

```
myCanvas.width = width;

setTimeout(function(){
    myContext.strokeStyle = '#000';
    myContext.moveTo(0, 0);
    myContext.lineTo(2000, 2000);
    myContext.stroke();
}, 100);
```

Both work fine on desktop browsers, but not in Safari iOS.

What's causing this and is setTimeout the best solution to get around it?

Thanks,

Comment: Smells like a race condition to me. I'm not sure why it's happening, but `setTimeout` can't be the best solution.

Comment: Thanks for your comment - I've added an answer, but my diagnosis of the problem was wrong.

Answer (score 0):

My mistake.  Turns out the setTimeout had nothing to do with it.

What I did discover though that might help others is that there is a maximum size allowed for canvasses in the browsers and this is surprisingly small on mobile browsers (e.g. Safari).

See this question for more info: [Maximum size of a <canvas> element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6081483/maximum-size-of-a-canvas-element)

I was trying to render a canvas too large for iPhone.