# ThreeJS updating texture with HTML canvas gives "WebGL: INVALID_VALUE: texImage2D: no canvas" on mobile (iPhone Safari, etc)

Tags: javascript, html, ios, three.js, webgl

I am trying to update a `THREE.Texture` ".image" property with an HTML5 canvas object. This works on Chromium (MacOSX) on my laptop. However, iPhone Safari and iPhone Chrome both does not work. What could be the root cause and how to fix this?

Using Web Inspector in Safari, I get this error message:

> WebGL: INVALID_VALUE: texImage2D: no canvas.

I made sure the canvas is completely drawn before being updated, using the below code to update the material:

```js
material.map.image = loaded_canvas[curr_id]; // loaded_canvas stores canvas that has been completed loaded already, drawn by Image() objects.
material.map.needsUpdate = true;
```

Here is how material is used:

```js
var geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(100.0, 32, 32);
var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
    map: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture(image_path),
    side: THREE.BackSide,
});
```

Strangely, if I use `THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture` to load an image, it works fine. However, my use case is that I have to use an canvas object (multiple images on a canvas).

Thanks.

Comment: I met similar issue, do you have any results?

Comment: Just stumbled across the same error. Any luck in finding a solution?

Comment: @voondo This question is 4 years old. Are you still seeing issues? Are you using the latest version of three.js (currently r109)? The current version supports [`CanvasTexture`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/textures/CanvasTexture).

Comment: [Here's an article](https://threejsfundamentals.org/threejs/lessons/threejs-canvas-textures.html) otherwise post a [snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/). What size is your canvas? iPhone browsers only support max 4096x4096 IIRC

Answer (score 5):

According to the [`Texture` docs](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/textures/Texture.image), the .image property is more of a "getter" for the image element created via the `TextureLoader.load()` method. If you want to create a texture with a `<canvas>` element, you can create it with `new THREE.Texture(canvas);` as demonstrated via the snippet below. The texture creation takes place in the `makeCanvasTexture()` function:

```js
function makeCanvasTexture() {
    // Create canvas context
    var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
    canvas.width = 32;
    canvas.height = 32;

    // Draw radial gradient
    var grad = context.createRadialGradient(16, 16, 6, 16, 16, 16);
    grad.addColorStop(0, "rgba(255, 150, 0, 1.0");
    grad.addColorStop(0.5, "rgba(255, 0, 150, 1.0");
    grad.addColorStop(1, "rgba(0, 150, 255, 1.0)");
    context.fillStyle = grad;
    context.fillRect(0, 0, 32, 32);

    // Use canvas to create texture
    var canvasTexture = new THREE.Texture(canvas);
    canvasTexture.needsUpdate = true;

    return canvasTexture;
}

// Boilerplate Three.js setup
var camera, scene, renderer;
renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({antialias: true});
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
scene = new THREE.Scene();
scene.background = new THREE.Color(0xe1e1e1);
camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(35, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 100);
camera.position.set(0, 30, -30);
camera.lookAt(0, 0, 0);

const ambient = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xddeeff, 1);
ambient.position.set(0, 1, 1);

// Using canvas as material map texture:
const floor = new THREE.Mesh(
    new THREE.BoxBufferGeometry(20, 0.25, 20),
    new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({map: makeCanvasTexture()})
);

scene.add(ambient, floor);

function animate(t) {
 // Animate mesh
    floor.rotation.z += Math.sin(t * 0.001) * 0.1;
 renderer.render(scene, camera);
 requestAnimationFrame(animate);
}

animate(0);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/109/three.min.js"></script>
```

Keep in mind that WebGL texture size is limited depending on each device's graphics card capabilities, so you'll get errors if you try to create a canvas that breaches this limitation. You can see the limit of your current device by visiting https://webglreport.com/ and looking at the "Max texture size" readout on the right. Mine is 8192px².

[image]

Likewise, you can access this information programmatically with `THREE.WebGLRenderer.capabilities.maxTextureSize` as explained [in this documentation page](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/renderers/WebGLRenderer.capabilities) so you can use this number to prevent canvas sizes from going beyond the device's limit.

Comment: Working on my end 

Answer (score 0):

This is is probably **fixed** from this commit on d3-x3d, [Fix #14 texImage2D: no canvas.](https://github.com/jamesleesaunders/d3-x3d/commit/3c80f3781fea0a6fa8825254e5813a03f5a1505f) which is related to this (already closed) issue, [INVALID_VALUE: texImage2D: no canvas](https://github.com/jamesleesaunders/d3-x3d/issues/14).

If the problem still persists, this is possibly related to the limitations of each browser on their maximum supported canvas dimensions/area.

Please refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11585939/2678218) answer from another post to look for the said limitations per browser.

> Exceeding the maximum length/width/area on most browsers renders the canvas unusable. (It will ignore any draw commands, even in the usable area.)
>   - [Brandon Gano](https://stackoverflow.com/users/129127/brandon-gano)

Unfortunately there's no given figures for Safari from the upvoted answer, but you may look for the comments under it like:

> iOS 9.3.1 Safari on an iPhone 6 Plus is limited to an area of 16777216 pixels (for example, 4096 x 4096)
>   - [matb33](https://stackoverflow.com/users/962223/matb33)

Or look into the other answers of the post like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23391599/2678218)

> Therefore, any size variation of 5242880 (5 x 1024 x 1024) pixels will
>   work on large memory devices, otherwise it's 3145728 pixels.
>
> Example for 5 megapixel canvas (width x height):
>
> ```
> Any total <= 5242880
> --------------------
> 5 x 1048576 ~= 5MP   (1048576 = 1024 x 1024)
> 50 x 104857 ~= 5MP
> 500 x 10485 ~= 5MP
> ```
>
> and so on..
>
> The largest SQUARE canvases are ("MiB" = 1024x1024 Bytes):
>
> ```
> device < 256 MiB   device >= 256 MiB   iPhone 6 [not confirmed]
> -----------------  -----------------   ---------------------
> <= 3145728 pixels  <= 5242880 pixels   <= 16 x 1024 x 1024 p
> 1773 x 1773        2289 x 2289         4096 x 4096
> ```
>
> -[dcbarans](https://stackoverflow.com/users/198178/dcbarans)

Another possible factor is the client side's graphics card.