# HTML5 Canvas Memory Issue in IE

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, html5-canvas

I am creating a HTML5 game using canvas. I am getting an error when running the game in IE. The error message is "Not enough storage is available to complete this operation". The error occurs when calling ctx.drawImage. This only happens towards the end of the game. Several other images/sprites are draw in the exact same way throughout the game without any issues. This do not happen when using Chrome or Firefox. Any suggestions?

Here is my flow:

1) At the start of the game, I load several images into an array called Game.sprites

```
var imageObj = new Image();
imageObj.src = assetDir + "Images/myImage.png";
Game.sprites.myAnimation = new AnimatedSpriteSheet(imageObj, 0, 0, 1200, 1200, 4, 14);
```

I do the above for about 100 sprite sheets

```
function AnimatedSpriteSheet(img, startX, startY, width, height, imagesPerRow, imageCount){
  this.img = img;
  this.startX = startX;
  this.startY = startY;
  this.width = width;
  this.height = height;
  this.imagesPerRow = imagesPerRow;
  this.imageCount = imageCount;
}


AnimatedSpriteSheet.prototype.draw = function(ctx, posX, posY, width, height, imageIndex){
try{
    //Determine position of image to draw
    var row = Math.floor(imageIndex/this.imagesPerRow);
    var column = imageIndex%this.imagesPerRow;
    ctx.drawImage(this.img, this.startX + (column*this.width), this.startY + (row*this.height), this.width, this.height, posX, posY, width, height);
    return true;
  }catch(err){
    console.log("Error: AnimatedSpriteSheet.draw for image " + this.img.href + " " + err.message);
    return false;
  }
}
```

2) During the game I add certain images to an array called Game.sceneObjects.

```
Game.sceneObjects.push(new MyAnimationObject("", Game.sprites.myAnimation, Game.cWidth*.3, Game.cHeight*.3, Game.cWidth*.4, Game.cWidth*.4, 0, 2));

function MyAnimationObject(tag, obj, x, y, width, height, startIndex, ticksPerFrame){
  this.tag = tag;
  this.obj = obj;
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;
  this.width = width;
  this.height = height;
  this.currentIndex = startIndex;
  this.tickCount = 0;
  this.ticksPerFrame = ticksPerFrame;
};

MyAnimationObject.prototype.draw = function(ctx){
  this.obj.draw(ctx, this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height, this.currentIndex);
};

MyAnimationObject.prototype.update = function(){
  this.tickCount += 1;
  if (this.tickCount > this.ticksPerFrame){
      this.tickCount = 0;
      if (this.currentIndex < this.obj.imageCount - 1){
          this.currentIndex += 1;
      }
  }
};
```

3) I draw each image in the sceneObjects array

```
Game.ctx.clearRect(0,0, Game.cWidth, Game.cHeight);
$.each(Game.sceneObjects, function(key, value){
  value.draw(Game.ctx);
});
```

4) At the beginning of a new screen/scene I clear the object out.

```
for (var i = 0; i < Game.sceneObjects.length; i++){
    delete Game.sceneObjects[i];
}
Game.sceneObjects = [];
```

UPDATE:

If I start the game in the middle or after the middle, the end does not have this issue. It is only if I start the game sometime before the middle. There is some kind of memory issue, but I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 2):

You're not really clearing your `sceneObjects` array.

The `delete` command will only set the specified array element as `undefined`, but won't remove it from the array. It is the equivalent of this:

```
// element 5362 equals undefined but is still an element in the array
Game.sceneObjects[5362]=undefined;
```

Instead, set the array length to zero. This causes the array to have no elements.

```
Game.sceneObjects.length=0;
```

Comment: But, there is no more link to element, and gc will remove it from memory if undefined, or not?

Comment: Not to worry...The empty array itself (Game.sceneObjects) is still referenced (still exists) and will not be garbage collected.

Comment: @markE - I removed the delete and replace it with the setting the length to 0 for the array. It is still having the same issue. I looked at the memory profile and it still shows the memory increasing every new scene.

Answer (score 0):

It is because of ie max size canvas limit.Read this post [canvas size limit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6081483/maximum-size-of-a-canvas-element). What version of IE do you use?Your solution will be not exceed this limits (result canvas width and height)

Comment: My canvas size is 1020px x 680px. MSDN says the max size is 8192px x 8192px. Each image I draw to the canvas is smaller then the canvas.