# FabricJS toDataURL method with multiplier option creates non-valid bitmap file

Tags: javascript, canvas, fabricjs

I am using the toDataURL method of FabricJS with a multiplier. However, when I try to download and open the file, in paint for example, it throws the following error:

> This is not a valid bitmap file, or its format is not currently supported

However, if I don't use the multiplier, it works. I am using Chrome and my dimensions when multiplied are 11610 x 7800 (initially it is 774 x 520) so it is within the bounds stated here: [Maximum size of a <canvas> element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6081483/maximum-size-of-a-canvas-element)

Here is my canvas HTML:

```
 <canvas id ="c"></canvas>
```

Here is my canvas creation JavaScript:

```
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c', {
});

canvas.setWidth(774);
canvas.setHeight(520);
```

Example 1: No multiplier (works):

```
var img = canvas.toDataURL({
format: "png",
});

document.write('<img src="' + img + '"/>');
```

Example 2: Multiplier (doesn't work/bitmap error):

```
var img = canvas.toDataURL({
format: "png",
multiplier: 15
});

document.write('<img src="' + img + '"/>');
```

**Update:**

This appears to only be happening with files that have a dimension larger than 10,000 pixels.

Comment: I am using Chrome so it is less than the max in this case.

Comment: 15x774= 11610 < 32767

Comment: Apologies, I have updated my post. I have also noticed that it will open in Paint.NET but not Paint, but within Paint I can create images with dimensions greater than 11610x7800 so I am unsure why it can't open something that is 11610x7800.

Comment: Oh missed that point so you mean that the image is actually visible in the browser too? Then the problem comes from Paint and I can't help and am not sure if SO is the right place.

Comment: Yes, if I go the route in post, I can inspect the element using the document write method and it displays as 11610x7800. I then download it via a save as... but when I try to open in Paint, I get the error

Comment: Can you try setting your canvas this size and then call the toDataURL without multiplier ?

Comment: Yes, when I try that, I get the same error. Looks like it may be paint then...

Comment: Then the problem has nothing to do with FabricJS...