# EDGE cant copy large images using JS in to a canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I have this code, with copy parts from the image  "smoothchartshowAnalisysCopy" (500px X 250px) in to the large one "analysisFullGraph1" (32172px X 250px).

And it is **working well for** IE, firefox, chrome, safari e vivaldi, **but not** that OK for Edge...

Edge, only can copy  for the begin of the large image... maybe the max possition of 14000px...

```
var c   = document.getElementById('analysisFullGraph1'); 32172px X 250px
var ctx = c.getContext('2d');

var imageNow = document.querySelector('#smoothchartshowAnalisysCopy');
var ctxImageNow = imageNow.getContext('2d');


function copy(){
    var elmnt  = document.querySelector('#analysisFullGraphContainer1');
    var x = elmnt.scrollLeft;
    var y = elmnt.scrollTop;
    var imgData = ctx.getImageData(x, 0, 828, 270);
    ctxImageNow.putImageData(imgData, 0, 0);

}
```

I cant find info on Microsoft DOCs, not even in google..

I appreciate any help ou tips!

Comment: which version of Edge?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Maximum size of a <canvas> element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6081483/maximum-size-of-a-canvas-element)

Comment: my edge is "Microsoft Edge 25.10586.0.0"  and "Microsoft EdgeHTML 13.10586"

Comment: sorry, I googled and found that my first question was irrelevant

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The maximum size of the rendered area on a canvas is from 0,0 to 8192 x 8192 pixels, regardless of the size of the canvas. For example, a canvas is created with a width and height of 8292 pixels. A rectangular fill is then applied as "ctx.fillRect (0,0, canvas.width, canvas.height)".Only the area within the coordinates (0, 0, 8192, 8192) can be rendered, leaving a 100 pixel border on the right and bottom of the canvas. [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff975062(v=vs.85).aspx)

I searched for microsoft edge canvas size limit - it was the second link