# How to fix "Total canvas memory use exceeds the maximum limit (256MB)" error on iPad

Tags: konvajs

I have a KonvaJS app with a "draw" functionality. On the mouse move event, I'm creating a new Line and adding points to it.

It works perfect on Desktop but it crashes on iPad. This is the issue that I get:

```
Total canvas memory use exceeds the maximum limit (256MB)
```

It's fired on this part of the KonvaJS library:

```
setHeight: function(t) {
    this.height = this._canvas.height = t * this.pixelRatio, this._canvas.style.height = t + "px";
    var e = this.pixelRatio;
    this.getContext()._context.scale(e, e)
},
```

The line that fires the error is:

```
this.getContext()._context.scale(e, e)
```

By the way, I'm not sure if it's related, but in the mouse move event I'm running also this code to fix an issue with the scale property:

```
var newPos = stage.getPointerPosition();
var stageTransform = stage.getAbsoluteTransform().copy();
newPos = stageTransform.invert().point(newPos);
```

Any ideas of what can be the problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I would guess that you might need to change your underlying data model to be more memory efficient. Scaling could easily require double memory. What is the value of `e` in the  context of this issue.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. What do you mean with "underlying data model"? I'm sorry, I don't get the point. The value of `e` changes between `1` and `2`, but I'm not sure where it comes from.

Comment: I'm not familiar with this library. I'm thinking the canvas has too much going on, on it so you're experiencing these issues. You're running out of memory. You should take a profile of your code, and see what's eating the memory.

Comment: How many layers do you have? How large is the stage?

Comment: I have only one layer. The stage is 1240 x 1754. I just tried with a small one (400 x 400) and I can't reproduce the error. It seems like the problem is happening when the stage is too big. Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Total canvas memory use exceeds the maximum limit (Safari 12)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52532614/total-canvas-memory-use-exceeds-the-maximum-limit-safari-12)