# Cannot remove canvas elements from memory that are created but never appended to the page

Tags: javascript, canvas

I am creating a canvas element like this:

```
var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
```

I use this `canvas` object to get the context, and from there, use information from the context for further logic.

```
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

...

// More logic
```

I never append the canvas element to the document, or any other element, but using the safari devtools -> Canvas tab, I can see that the canvas elements are constantly being created whenever this code is run. They are about 200KB each, and there can be hundreds, thousands of these canvas elements created in one session. If the page is reloaded, they are removed from memory, and no longer appear in the canvas tab.

However, if the page is not reloaded and the canvas' build up, you can see a dip in performance.

So, how can I remove these canvas elements from memory if they have never been appended to the page?

See below a picture of the canvas tab (only works in Safari as newer versions of Chrome and Firefox don't support it). The first canvas object is expected, the other ones I would like to remove. I am using javascript and jquery.

[image]

Comment: Variables should be garbage collected once there is no longer a reference to them, have you check to see if you are accidentally keeping a history of canvases or storing them globally?

Comment: GC is an issue as soon as DOM is also involved. There were several easy ways to leak memory with js-DOM interactions, i am not up to date on which are still relevant, but this sounds much like one.

Comment: Garbage collection in JS is automatic, we'd have to see more code to help you debug the issue.

Comment: Related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52532614/total-canvas-memory-use-exceeds-the-maximum-limit-safari-12

Answer (score 3):

The problem comes from the very **canvas dev-tool**.
It is the one culprit that will keep references to these canvas elements and prevent the Garbage-Collector to do its work correctly.

As a proof, try to run the following snippet, first with the dev-tools closed, then with it open on the "canvas" tab.

```js
var canvas, context;
for (let i=0; i<100; i++) {
  canvas = document.createElement( 'canvas' );
  canvas.width = canvas.height = 5000;
  context = canvas.getContext( '2d' );
}
console.log( 'done' );
```

When the dev-tools are closed, it runs seamlessly on Safari.
Opening it after the "done" message appeared will reveal that a single canvas is active on the page.

[image: Screenshot taken from my Safari 12.1.2 showing a single active canvas]

However with the dev-tools open, it will start to stutter until some message appear in the console.

> "[Warning] Total canvas memory use exceeds the maximum limit ..."

And in the canvas panel, we'll have all the ones generated before this message pops out marked as active.

[image: Screenshot taken from my Safari 12.1.2 showing several active canvases]

---

So to avoid it, avoid creating so much canvases while this tool is open.

Note that according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52532614/total-canvas-memory-use-exceeds-the-maximum-limit-safari-12), as originally proposed by user [minimo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10431860/minimo), setting the `width` and `height` attributes of the canvas after use will minimize this issue, which makes perfect sense since now the browser only has a 0 x 0px buffer to keep in memory.