# HTML5 Canvas Very Long Line Is Cutted In Other Browser

Tags: html, canvas, html5-canvas

I have these specific codes in html but the problem is the line I draw is cutted in firefox and internet explorer.

Here is my sample html.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<canvas id="myCanvas" width="200" height="100" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;">
Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.</canvas>

<script>
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
c.setAttribute("width", "10000");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
ctx.moveTo(1,10);
ctx.lineTo(10000,10);
ctx.stroke();
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what does "cutted" mean here? Could you share a screenshot of what you see, and your browsers version.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6081483/maximum-size-of-a-canvas-element