# HTML2CANVAS not rendering the document.body when its more than 30,000 pixels long

Tags: javascript, html, html2canvas

is there anyway to solve this issue? The html2canvas is not rendering when the document.body height is more than 30,000 pixels. Or can i render the current viewport only? On what the user can see?

Please help.

Comment: You can add `type:'view'` in html2canvas initialization options to render only the active viewport

Comment: @AmrLabib you can probably add this as an answer (except if you know a good duplicate). Just for info: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6081483/maximum-size-of-a-canvas-element

Comment: I already add the type:'view' but when i scroll down it still rendering whats on the top of the page..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be able to render only current active viewport you can initialize html2canvas with `type:'view'` option

example:

```
 var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0]; 
    html2canvas(body, {
        type: 'view',
        onrendered: function(canvas) {
            //implementation
        }
    })
```

I tested the above code with `html2canvas` version `0.5.0-beta4` and it capture only the current viewport correctly, even if you scroll to the bottom of the page

Regarding 30,000 pixels, you can check the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6081483/maximum-size-of-a-canvas-element) mentioned by @kaiido

Comment: What if my page is 40,000 pixels does it still work ?

Comment: Yes i just tested it again with 40,000 pixels body and scrolled to the bottom, it's capturing only the bottom active viewport

Comment: Sir can i ask how to download the html2canvas version 0.5.0-beta4 because i downloaded html2canvas.js https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas/releases here but theres an error saying "Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: this.getChildren is not a function"..thanks

Comment: Just use `npm install html2canvas` it will download the latest version which is `0.5.0-beta4`

Comment: Okay sir ill try it. Ill ask you later or tomorrow

Comment: sir i already downloaded the html2canvas should i import all the files ?

html2canvas.js
html2canvas.min
html2canvas.svg
html2canvas.svg.min

Comment: you just need this file `node_modules/html2canvas/dist/html2canvas.js` if you have issues downloading the package you can just add it to your page from cdn https://cdnjs.com/libraries/html2canvas/0.5.0-beta4

Comment: can i use the latest html2canvas.js in feedback.js?