# Html2Canvas Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: this.getPseudoElement is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, prototype, html2canvas

I encountered this error on html2canvas. This is the error

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: this.getPseudoElement is not a function
    at NodeParser.getPseudoElements (html2canvas.js:1960)
    at prototype.js:297
    at prototype.js:266
    at Array._each (prototype.js:472)
    at Array.each (prototype.js:264)
    at Array.collect (prototype.js:296)
    at new NodeParser (html2canvas.js:1861)
    at renderWindow (html2canvas.js:1018)
    at html2canvas.js:1005
    at <anonymous>
```

This is the code on html2canvas

html2canvas:

```
NodeParser.prototype.getPseudoElements = function(container) {
    var nodes = [[container]];
    if (container.node.nodeType === Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
        var before = this.getPseudoElement(container, ":before");
        var after = this.getPseudoElement(container, ":after");

        if (before) {
            nodes.push(before);
        }

        if (after) {
            nodes.push(after);
        }
    }
    return flatten(nodes);
};
```

the getPseudoElement is this

```
NodeParser.prototype.getPseudoElement = function(container, type) {
    var style = container.computedStyle(type);
    if(!style || !style.content || style.content === "none" || style.content === "-moz-alt-content" || style.display === "none") {
        return null;
    }

    var content = stripQuotes(style.content);
    var isImage = content.substr(0, 3) === 'url';
    var pseudoNode = document.createElement(isImage ? 'img' : 'html2canvaspseudoelement');
    var pseudoContainer = new PseudoElementContainer(pseudoNode, container, type);

    for (var i = style.length-1; i >= 0; i--) {
        var property = toCamelCase(style.item(i));
        pseudoNode.style[property] = style[property];
    }

    pseudoNode.className = PseudoElementContainer.prototype.PSEUDO_HIDE_ELEMENT_CLASS_BEFORE + " " + PseudoElementContainer.prototype.PSEUDO_HIDE_ELEMENT_CLASS_AFTER;

    if (isImage) {
        pseudoNode.src = parseBackgrounds(content)[0].args[0];
        return [pseudoContainer];
    } else {
        var text = document.createTextNode(content);
        pseudoNode.appendChild(text);
        return [pseudoContainer, new TextContainer(text, pseudoContainer)];
    }
};
```

I tried to comment out the prototype.js and its work. How can i avoid the js error on prototype.js?
please help.

this is my code on how i use the html2canvas

```
window.MakeWish.Screenshot.prototype.render = function() {
/*document.body.style.overflow = 'hidden';*/



this.dom = document.createElement("div");
document.body.className += " capture-body";
// execute the html2canvas script
var script,
$this = this,
options = this.options;
document.body.style.backgroundColor = "white";
var runH2c = function(){
    try {
        /*option.testTop = scrollValueX;
        options.logging = true;
        options.onrendered = options.onrendered || function( canvas ) {


        };*/
         var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0]; 
         console.log(body);
html2canvas(body, {
    logging:true,
    type: 'view',
    onrendered: function(canvas) {
            $this.h2cCanvas = canvas;
            $this.h2cDone = true;

    }
})
    /*    window.html2canvas([ document.body ], options);*/



    } catch( e ) {
        $this.h2cDone = true;
        log("Error in html2canvas: " + e.message);
    }
};

if ( window.html2canvas === undefined && script === undefined ) {

    // let's load html2canvas library while user is writing message

    script = document.createElement("script");
    script.src = options.h2cPath || "libs/html2canvas.js";
    script.onerror = function() {
        log("Failed to load html2canvas library, check that the path is correctly defined");
    };

    script.onload = (scriptLoader)(script, function() {

        if (window.html2canvas === undefined) {
            log("Loaded html2canvas, but library not found");
            return;
        }

        window.html2canvas.logging = window.MakeWish.debug;
        runH2c();


    });

    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    s.parentNode.insertBefore(script, s);

} else {
    // html2canvas already loaded, just run it then
    runH2c();
}
return this;
```

};

and i added var $this at html2canvas because the first error is

```
html2canvas.js:2012 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: this.getChildren is not a function
at html2canvas.js:2012
at prototype.js:297
at prototype.js:266
at Array._each (prototype.js:472)
at Array.each (prototype.js:264)
at Array.collect (prototype.js:296)
at NodeParser.getChildren (html2canvas.js:2010)
at new NodeParser (html2canvas.js:1859)
at renderWindow (html2canvas.js:1018)
at html2canvas.js:1005
```

so i added this var $this = this;

```
NodeParser.prototype.getChildren = function(parentContainer) { 
var $this = this;
return flatten([].filter.call(parentContainer.node.childNodes, renderableNode).map(function(node) {
    var container = [node.nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE ? new TextContainer(node, parentContainer) : new NodeContainer(node, parentContainer)].filter(nonIgnoredElement);
    return node.nodeType === Node.ELEMENT_NODE && container.length && node.tagName !== "TEXTAREA" ? (container[0].isElementVisible() ? container.concat($this.getChildren(container[0])) : []) : container;
}, this));
```

};

Comment: does `NodeParser.prototype` have a `getPseudoElement` method?

Comment: yes theres a method

Comment: so `NodeParser.prototype` has both `getPseudoElements ` and `getPseudoElement` methods - because the error suggests otherwise

Comment: what is the solution for this? to avoid the js error in prototype.js

Comment: what is the relevance of `prototype.js` ... all objects in javascript have a `prototype` property which has nothing to do with `prototype.js`

Comment: here's what you need to post ... how are you trying to use `html2canvas` - so far you posted an error, where the line numbers don't match the line numbers in the current (beta) html2canvas.js, and some code from html2canvas.js - how about posting your code that uses html2canvas, and which version of html2canvas you are using

Comment: im using  html2canvas 0.5.0-beta4 <http://html2canvas.hertzen.com>

Comment: I tried to download that, but it gave me 0.5.0-beta3 !! Have you tried the current "stable" release

Comment: what version is that? i didnt try the stable version yet because i need to render only the viewport

Comment: i download it using npm

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46881957/html2canvas-not-rendering-the-document-body-when-its-more-than-30-000-pixels-lon/46882232?noredirect=1#comment80712449_46882232 check here