# How can i change default max canvas size?

Tags: javascript, canvas, iframe, todataurl

I saw on the Internet the different max size and area of a canvas. I would like to change them for my project because i create canvas of 5000px / 2600px. I test to put a smaller canvas (300px / 300px) and it works i've no error (NS_ERROR_FAILURE)

Thank's all

Comment: The underlying implementation is failing, almost certainly due to the large size of your canvas.

Comment: Thank's, i think too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Canvas size is device dependent. Have a look at [Maximum size of a <canvas> element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6081483/maximum-size-of-a-canvas-element), this may help you to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You may use CSS for that, in your webpage.

```
<head>
<style>
canvas{
       width: 300px;
       height: 300px;
}
</style>
</head>
```

Comment: Thank you for helping but i already tried it, I saw on the internet that maybe it was because a canvas should not exceed 4096/4096. There is no solution i think

Answer (score 0):

You can't change the maximum canvas size supported by a browser, but you can detect it and avoid creating canvas elements that exceed the browser's size limitations.

See my answer in the [Maximum size of a <canvas> element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6081483/maximum-size-of-a-canvas-element/53677532#53677532) thread for details.