# Haxe Drawing Lines on Canvas

Tags: html5-canvas, haxe

Can anyone help me look at this, I'm trying to draw lines on a canvas and it works in Edge, but in Firefox and Chrome the canvas goes black with a little frowny face in the top left corner. Code:

```
var cellwitdh = StaticData.SelectedTileSheet.getCellWidth();
var col = Math.floor(_gridCVS.width / cellwitdh);
var ctx = this._gridCVS.getContext2d();
for (i in 0...col)
{
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(i cellwitdh, 0);
    ctx.lineTo(i cellwitdh, this._gridCVS.width);
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.closePath();
}
```

[image]
I don't get any error messages, just this image

Answer (score 2):

The canvas was too big, I was trying to do a canvas size 24000x24000;

[answer reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6081483/maximum-size-of-a-canvas-element)