# it show Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'createObjectURL' on 'URL': Overload resolution failed

Tags: javascript, html, css, html2canvas

when I try to use file saver and html2canvas it show that error, How to fix this ?

> Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'createObjectURL' on 'URL':
> Overload resolution failed.

```
$( "#click" ).on( "click", function() {
    html2canvas(document.querySelector("#Views")).then(canvas => {
      canvas.toBlob(function(blob) {

        window.saveAs(blob, 'img.jpg');
      });
      });
  });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error means that the call to `HTMLCanvasElement#toBlob()` failed, this can happen for a couple of reasons:

- The returned canvas had either its `height` or `width` set to `0`:

```js
document.querySelector("canvas").toBlob(console.log);
```

```html
<canvas width="0">
```

- The returned canvas's area exceeded the [maximum area the browser could support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6081483/maximum-size-of-a-canvas-element):

```js
document.querySelector("canvas").toBlob(console.log);
```

```html
<canvas width="80000" height="80000">
```

So you should check your element's computed style, taking particular attention to its size, but also to its `display` value, since this problem is quite frequently caused by targeting an element with `display: none`.