# Chart js height limitation

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I am working on displaying gantt chart using chartJS in SalesForce. I have over 2000 timeline records (bars) to be displayed. While I am able to show them, on trying to increase the height of the canvas parent container so that the labels and bars are distinctly readable, the chart breaks up.

I tried to build a simple horizontal chart in a HTML page to see if there is any limitation and to rule out any code from my project was interfering. However even on plain html, I am seeing same issue.

Is there really any limitation to the height that can be setup for the chart. Else is there any other way to increase the distance between the y axis ticks so that any two bars and labels are distinctly readable. In my requirement I also need to wrap the y axis labels hence need more space. I don't see any padding like attribute between y axis ticks in the documentation.
Looking for some advise here.

```js
const arrLabel = [];
const arrData = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 2000; i++) {
  arrLabel.push('Label' + i);
  arrData.push(i);
}

const data = {
  labels: arrLabel,
  datasets: [{
    label: 'Weekly Sales',
    data: arrData
  }]
};

// config 
const config = {
  type: 'bar',
  data,
  options: {
    maintainAspectRatio: false,
    responsive: true,
    indexAxis: 'y',
    scales: {
      y: {
        ticks: {
          autoSkip: false
        }
      }
    }
  }
};

// render init block
const myChart = new Chart(
  document.getElementById('myChart'),
  config
);
const num_bars = config.data.labels.length;
const bar_Height = 250 + (num_bars) * 20;
myChart.canvas.parentNode.style.height = `${bar_Height}px`;
myChart.resize();
```

```html
<div style="height: 500px; max-height: 250px; overflow-y: scroll">
  <div>
    <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
  </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js/dist/chart.umd.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chartjs-adapter-date-fns/dist/chartjs-adapter-date-fns.bundle.min.js"></script>
```

[screenshot of the chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C5f3C.png)

Comment: Does [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11585939/16466946) answer your question?

Comment: Those limits are clearly still actual: tested on chromw/macos: with `num_bars` * 15 canvas height was 30250 and it works fine; with `num_bars` * 20, the height is 40250 and it breaks at about 1629's bar, 1629/2000 * 40250 = 32783

Comment: @kikon Yeah it breaks when I try to give 20px to each bars. Is this basically a limitation of chart js? How can I ensure the bars are large enough to be readable along with the labels. Plz advise if you have any idea

Answer (score 0):

I realize that I was wrong in my messages, the limitation is indeed of chart.js; the canvas limits are
higher, as one can see from this pure canvas implementation (charome/macOS - 65535px)
and also, when the fails, it fails completely, doesn't mix the bars.

```js
const N = Math.floor(65535/20), barH = 20, iH = N * barH, iW = 500;
const canvas = document.querySelector('#myChart');
canvas.height = `${iH}`;
canvas.width = `${iW}`;
console.log('canvas height = '+canvas.offsetHeight);
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
ctx.fillStyle = '#aeddff';
for(let i = 0;  i < N; i++){
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.rect(75, i*20+1, (i+1)/N*(iW-95), barH-4);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.fill();
}
ctx.fillStyle = '#000';
ctx.font = `regular ${barH}px "'Helvetica Neue', 'Helvetica', 'Arial', sans-serif"`;
for(let i = 0;  i < N; i++){
    ctx.fillText("Label"+(i+1), 10, (i+1/2)*barH);
}
```

```html
<div style="min-height: 60vh; overflow: auto">
    <canvas id="myChart" style="background: #ddd">
    </canvas>
</div>
<br>
```

To determine the maximum canvas size on the current user environment,
one can use the library canvas-size.

The actual chart.js limitation is caused by the function [_int16](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/tree/v4.4.1/src/helpers/helpers.math.ts#L187)
that is called by `scale`'s method [getPixelForDecimal](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/tree/v4.4.1/src/core/core.scale.js#L927);
those make the maximum pixel value for any position computed by a scale to 32767.

Just to prove that that's the case, here's a version with a hacked  `getPixelForDecimal`, that does go to 65535px on those environments that support it.

```js
//  don't do this in production, just experimental!
Chart.Scale.prototype.getPixelForDecimal = function(decimal) {
    if (this._reversePixels) {
        decimal = 1 - decimal;
    }
    const pixel = this._startPixel + decimal * this._length;
    // original code:
    //return _int16Range(this._alignToPixels ? _alignPixel(this.chart, pixel, 0) : pixel);
    return this._alignToPixels ? Chart.helpers._alignPixel(this.chart, pixel, 0) : pixel;
}

const arrLabel = [];
const arrData = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 3200; i++) {
    arrLabel.push('Label' + i);
    arrData.push(i);
}

const data = {
    labels: arrLabel,
    datasets: [{
        label: 'Weekly Sales',
        data: arrData
    }]
};

// config
const config = {
    type: 'bar',
    data,
    options: {
        maintainAspectRatio: false,
    devicePixelRatio: 1, // this is needed to avoid `retinaScale` assigning 1.5 which
                               // creates a canvas with a height 1.5 times the required one
        responsive: true,
        indexAxis: 'y',
        scales: {
            y: {
                ticks: {
                    autoSkip: false
                }
            }
        }
    }
};

// render init block
const myChart = new Chart(
    document.getElementById('myChart'),
    config
);
const num_bars = config.data.labels.length;
const bar_Height = 250 + (num_bars) * 20;
myChart.canvas.parentNode.style.height = `${bar_Height}px`;
myChart.resize();
setTimeout(()=>console.log('canvas size = ' + myChart.canvas.offsetHeight), 1000);
```

```html
<div style="height: 500px; max-height: 250px; overflow-y: scroll">
    <div>
        <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
    </div>
</div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/4.4.1/chart.umd.js" integrity="sha512-ZwR1/gSZM3ai6vCdI+LVF1zSq/5HznD3ZSTk7kajkaj4D292NLuduDCO1c/NT8Id+jE58KYLKT7hXnbtryGmMg==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```

That hack should not be used in production, for obvious reasons.

The chart js limit of 32767 is predictable and not very far from the current limit of most browsers.